# how to remove gap between divs and body

Tags: html, css

I Created a web page but found problem that my all divs of header, container and footer are away from left and right side of body.  there is gap between left and right side of divs and body, I tried left & right padding and margin but nothing worked. there is no gab between top and bottom side.

Comment: Add html and css code in your question.

Comment: where is your try ? paste your code of fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Remove default margin, padding and border for html and body tags:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure Samurai's answer probably fixed your issue, but here is the "teach a man to fish" answer that might help you in the future. :)

What you should do is load up the page in Firefox (Preferably with Firebug) and right click on the element and hit inspect element with firebug.

Looking in the HTML tab you want to look over to the right and there is a panel that should have "Styles" selected. Look in there to see what rule is affecting it, you might find that a different stylesheet or default values are taking precedence.

You can also press the layout tab and it will show you any padding and/or margin that might be present. :)